# Microsoft Automation UI mouse click on a given position

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

I am developing a C# console application that will open up an application and do some stuff there. I am able to launch the app and login to app. I need to do some mouse click operation on specific positions though but could not find how to do it. Is it possible to simulate it? I must use the position because I need what I want to do is not just clicking on a button or textbox. I need to do a right click on main window and choose something from the opening menu. I am not sure there is a way to do it with Microsoft Automation UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download Microsoft.TestApi from Nuget.

```
using Microsoft.Test.Input;
using System.Drawing;

Mouse.MoveTo(new Point(1000, 1000));
Mouse.Click(MouseButton.Right);
```

Also, you can use Teststack.White for such automation purposes.

Comment: If I use Teststack.White it will be a test, right? What I want to do is to run an application and make it generate some data during the night so that I can see the results in the morning. Also some other friends will use it and they don't have visual studio installed on their machines. So I think console app is better. I could use autoIt as well but I found it more complicated.

Comment: White is just a library for interacting with windows application. You can create standalone console app with it, not test only

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you so much. Good to know it.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft.TestApi](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestApi) should be able to click on a coordinate you provide. Take a look at the [Mouse](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.TestApi/TestApiCore/Mouse) class' MoveTo method.

You'll probably have to get the coordinates via WinAPI's [GetClientRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503.aspx) method though. Alternatively, you can use the TestApi in conjunction with UIAutomation as you were intending to use. Get the AutomationElement of your launched process by getting the window handle, then you can navigate the visual tree with UIAutomation, and use [GetClickablePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.getclickablepoint(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a Point object that you can pass to the TestApi's Mouse.MoveTo() method.